# Does Pascal's Wager fail archimedean property?

Tags: decision-theory, expected-utility, rationality

I assume most people have heard of Pascal's Wager, in case you have not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_Wager

By the Stanford encyclopedia of philosphy:

*"We have a decision under risk, with probabilities assigned to the ways the world could be, and utilities assigned to the outcomes. In particular, we represent the infinite utility associated with salvation as ‘∞’. We assume that the real line is extended to include the element ‘∞’, and that the basic arithmetical operations are extended as follows:
For all real numbers r: ∞+r=∞. 
For all real numbers r: ∞×r=∞ if r>0."*

Doesn't this contradict one of the axioms of the expected utility theory? In particular the archimedean property states:

*Let l, l’ and l’’ be three lotteries in L such that $l \succ l’ \succ l’’$. Then there are $p,q \in(0,1)$ such that:
$pl + (1-p)l’’ \succ l’ \succ ql + (1-q)l’’$*

and it basically means that there are no infinitely preferred or infinitely despised lotteries.

But in the Pascal's Wager, $l$ = salvation = $ + \infty$, $l'$ = nothing (god doesn't exist), $l''$ = damnation = $ - \infty$,
but then there does not exist a probability $p > 0$ such that any mixed combination of damnation and salvation is strictly preferred than "god doesn't exist".
What do you think?

Comment: Why do you assume damnation is $-\infty$? 0 seems to work just as well.

Comment: You're right, but even without it the archimedean property is still violated.

Comment: Yes, you seem to be correct. The wager's lotteries also seem to violate continuity.